# How to safely develop with untrusted NPM modules on my own laptop?

Tags: security, npm, development-environment

I only realised relatively recently that running `npm install <foo>` on my own machine is completely unsafe. Anyone can publish *anything* to NPM, and even if there was some way of verifying that an individual package was not nefarious, it would be extremely difficult to verify all of its dependencies.

NPM runs with my user permissions (not `root`), but in the context of my Macbook, that's pretty much irrelevant, as all of my personal files are also owned by the same user. (The only thing `root` would add is the ability to destroy the operating system itself, which is vastly less important.)

So: how do people safely run untrusted code from NPM? Obviously running everything inside a VM is safer, but I always seem to have difficulties with local networking.

Or I guess I could create a new user, and make everything NPM-related owned by that user, who doesn't have access to the rest of my system.

Are there any other good options?

Answer (score 0):

Mitigations for this would include:

- If you are a user who owns modules you should not stay logged into
  npm. (Easily enough, `npm logout` and `npm login`)
- Use `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down your dependencies
- Use `npm install someModule --ignore-scripts`

Also see [this link](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability) and [this link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/node-js-package-manager-vulnerable-to-malicious-worm-packages-502216.shtml).

Be aware that a malicious module could introduce backdoors or vulnerabilities into any code built with it, if not noticed by the community.